# Textarea line break after ';" character

Tags: textarea, break, word-wrap

I have a textarea with dynamically added css code.

I want the css to look clean and want to know if its possible to split the lines after every ";" character.

```
I currently have it like this
--------------------|
display: inline;color: 
red;                |
                    |
                    |
                    |
                    |
--------------------

And want it to be like this automatically
--------------------|
display: inline;    |
color: red;         |
                    |
                    |
                    |
                    |
--------------------
```

Is there a way I can do this with jQuery or Javascript?

Comment: Sounds like you need some JavaScript that hooks in an onchange event that finds all ';' characters that are not at the end of a line and replace them with ';\n' (e.g. adds a new line after the semi-colon).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Using jQuery
var val = $('textarea').val();
$('textarea').val(val.replace(/;/g, ';\n'));

// Using plain javascript
var textarea = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];
textarea.value = textarea.value.replace(/;/g, ';\n');
```

Comment: Won't this add **extra** line breaks if there is already a line break after a semi-colon?

Comment: Sure it would, but according to the question above it seems like the string doesn't have any line breaks in it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to jQuery this should work;

So lets say you have a textarea:

```
<textarea id="myTextarea"></textarea>
```

You can wire up an onchange event handler to adjust the content.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myTextarea').change(function(){
    var oldVal = this.value;
    var contentSplitBySemiColons = oldVal.split(';');
    var thisFragment;
    for(var i=1;i<contentSplitBySemiColons.length;i++){
      thisFragment = contentSplitBySemiColons[i];
      if(thisFragment[0] != '\n'){
        contentSplitBySemiColons[i] = '\n' + thisFragment;
      }
    }
    this.value = contentSplitBySemiColons.join(';');
  });
});
```

Here's a JSFiddle of it in action if you want to try it out. http://jsfiddle.net/jeLscdm5/4/

Comment: This seems to be a good solution. although what would this code look like if I also wanted to remove any spaces before new css line?

Comment: I'd run a similar loop... splitting by `\n` characters... test each line that you care about for leading whitespace (spaces, tabs) and delete them... however this *could* remove intentional indentation within a selector (which depending on your users, may frustrate them)